# Autonum changed when insert a register in middle of table

Tags: ms-access, autonumber

I've detected a change in the way autonums are being managed in access. May be due to de access verions.

Till Access 2003, when I insert a record in the middle of a table that uses autonum key to create new record, the autonum counter keeps its original value. I mean:

- The ID field is an autonun, which actual value is 1000
- I insert a new record (using a query) with an ID value of 400

This is what happens:

- If I insert this record in one computer running access 2003 the ID autonum stays in 1000, so next record that is added recieves an ID of 1001. Good for me!
- If I insert this record in one computer running access 2010 the autonum IS SET to the last manually assigned value, so next record that is added recieves an ID of 401. Bad for me!

Am I wrong or this is due to the Access version? Is anything related to MDAC? Can I do something to avoid the autonum reset when inserting?

Thank you

Comment: The trivial answer is, that your application should never rely on a certain sequence of an autonumber as its only purpose is to uniquely identify the single record, thus it should contain no information beyond that. If you need custom sorting or information useful for the user, create a timestamp or separate fields.

Comment: I use the autonum to index and relational purposes. In this table sometimes I extract a record (copy record to another table and delete from original). Later, sometimes, I must recover that record (copy from backup table and insert again in original table). I must recover the original ID (not create a new one). Thats my problem. When inserting back the original record, now autonumber changes (it should not happen)

Comment: Gustav pointed it out very clearly: an autonumber's only purpose is to uniquely identify the single record, thus it should contain no information beyond that. You should seriously consider redesigning your apporach and implementation otherwise you will create a hack that nobody wants or needs. You said you'll need it for relational purposes. Consider a new foreign key then.

Comment: As you can see, the ID serves it purpose when recovering the record. However, if you do this regularly, consider adding a field, _Deleted_, to set to True when the record should be ignored and filter on that field being False. Recovering is then a snap: Set _Deleted_ to False.